# Is it possible to transfer a bluetooth signal via something else?

Tags: signal, communication, wireless, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

***Problem:*** *For example, I have 2 devices communicating with each other via  bluetooth. But there is a thick metal wall between these devices and this makes a difficulty between them.*

To fix it, can I use a reference bus,sensor or any device? This (third one) thing will be able to reach both devices and will help them to communicate because they cant communicate with each other easily because of the wall but this new third thing is able to reach both of them.

My question is what is this third thing? Or is there something like this?

Here is also an illustration to understand:

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking the relay node section could be of interrest https://www.cypress.com/file/473921/download

Comment: RF signals **reflect** on metal surfaces, you could try a large metal object of metal wall to reflect the signals. Maybe the surface needs to be slightly curved.

Comment: @Sorenp The documentation seems long. All I need is a reference to help those devices to transfer signals between them. I ll try to check documentation too. If you have any other suggestion, I ll be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Unfortunately I cant change the surface, Is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk you can't make a surface reflective without changing it... definition of change ;) But really, you actually do want to put a device there, so you're actually open to change. So, put a reflector there. Probably doesn't have to be large; wavelength of 2.4 GHz is 12.something cm.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If i didnt misunderstand, you want me to put another wall to reflect the **RF signals**. Or I am totally misunderstanding?

Comment: I think he is suggesting [something like this](https://www.caymanwireless.com/antennas/1212-es24-14.html) on the wall.  Maybe you could experiment with aluminum foil and a pie plate first.

Comment: @relayman357 then what about the area of htat plate. Should it be large ? This solution seems crazy:)

Comment: I don’t know.  You can experiment. Try a large frying pan if you have one.